# Cluster job scheduler: tools

Tags: python, cluster-computing, scheduler

we are trying to solve a problem related to cluster job scheduler.

The problem is the following we have a set of python scripts which are executed in a cluster, the launching process is currently done by means of the human interaction, I mean to start the test we have a bash script which interact with the cluster to request the resources needed for the execution. What we are intending to do is to build an automatic launching process (which should be sound in the sense that it realizes the job status and based on that wait the job ending, restart the execution, etc...). Basically we have to implement a layer between the user workstation and the cluster.

Another additional difficulty is that our layer must be clever enough to interact with the different cluster job schedulers. We wonder if there exists a tool or framework which help us to interact with the cluster without having to deal with each cluster scheduler details. We have searched in the web but we did not find anything suitable for our needs.

By the way the programming language we use is Python.

Thanks in advance!

Br.-

Answer (score 0):

Use supervisor: http://supervisord.org/
and celery http://www.celeryproject.org/
together

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ipcluster_tools.  The documentation is sparse but it is easy to use.